# update data through j-query popup

Tags: jquery

i want to retrieve data from database table and make a link to every retrieved field when i click the link a query popup open and in that popup there should be textboxes and a update button 
Is it possible to update data in jquery popup.

Comment: WE need waaay more information. ASP/PHP/Perl/Python/Ruby etc etc? mySQL, sqLite, oracle etc etc? ajax/non ajax? what the question is.

Comment: how any idea please or suggestion

Comment: i have a simple box when i click the link it work but the textboxes in the popup box were empty then how can i update the field

Comment: Hunter, you need to provide much more information about the platform, What webserver software is it, what langugare are available. Your question has a million answers where most will be wrong depending on where you need to do this, so specify if you want answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you successfully retrieved the data and displaying the retrieved fields along with the link?

I guess you are able to display the data along with the links to do the editing and you are stuck with edit and update part.

So, I think you are not much experienced with [Dom Manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/). Go through these things specially - [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/),  [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and practice a few demos.

Then go back to your code and do the following:-

1. while you are generating the html containing the retrieved data, assign them proper ids.
2. on clicking a link use `.text()` or `.html()` to read the value and again use them to put values to the input field of your popup (you have to use proper ids while generating the popups). Are you doing any such thing? You say on clicking your text box is empty. So, check very properly the ids that you are assigning during the html generation.
3. Then on submitting, I guess you want the data to be updated in db without a page reload. Then you have to use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Ask with more details if you are still stuck.